# I made a mistake in my source control mapping. How do I correct it?

Tags: tfs

I created a team project, say ProjectA
When I mapped it to my local folder, I found that the root server folder: ProjectA folder is not mapped. However the ProjectA folder within that IS mapped to the project. This is a problem as the BuildProcessTemplate is not included in source control and I cannot build my application.
How do I remove the mappings and start again?

Comment: Under old Visual Source Safe, you could (with care) open the user INI file and view, edit and/or remove the mappings. Sadly this doesn't appear to be an option with TFS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the source control explorer window in visual studio there is a drop down near the top for workspaces. When you originally mapped that folder, it created a workspace for you. If you want to change the mappings, it can be done by clicking the drop down and selecting the `Workspaces...` option. You can select your workspace and then click `Edit..` to change mappings. You can also delete your current workspace and create a new one if you feel so inclined.